# Testing pre-trend in DID

Tags: references, causality, difference-in-difference

I follow [Dasgupta, 2019](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/32/7/2587/5079300) to set up the control and treatment variables for staggered implementation of laws among countries as events. The treatment and control groups are explained in [one topic](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/43864/how-to-justify-the-treatment-and-control-groups-for-difference-in-difference-wit).

I am wondering if there is any reference paper or any explanation guiding **how to perform the pre-trend analysis (equation) for this case**. I did some searches and saw [this topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/523032/testing-parallel-trends-in-staggered-difference-in-differences). However, [the answer from the expert](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/523361/319998) not mention the econometrics way or the equation to test pre-trend analysis.

In [Dasgupta,2019, last paragraph, section 4.2,](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/32/7/2587/5079300) I saw a paragraph denoting how he conduct the pre-trend test

> To explore the dynamics of the issuance activities and leverage
> change, we create dummy variables corresponding to the following
> windows around the treatment year: from 1 to 4 years before the
> treatment; the treatment year and the 2 years after treatment; the
> next 3 years; and the years beyond. We find that firms first start
> growing and issuing equity over the first two sub-periods after the
> discussion about the leniency law passage started and there is no
> pre-trend once anticipation effect is taken into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you typically need at least two pre-periods for both treatment and control in order to consider pre-treatment trends. Based on my review of the paper it seems that they do indeed have two (*please correct me if that is incorrect!*).

The intuition of testing pre-trends is simple. Let us use potential outcomes notation where $Y_0$ refers to the non-treated potential outcome and $Y_1$ refers to the treated potential outcome. The intuition is that during the pre-treatment periods any observed change is a change in $Y_0$.

Often people will just eyeball this by plotting the outcome over periods prior to treatment and periods post-treatment. Figure 1 seems to do this in the paper.

A more formal test could also be concocted. What you could do here is to drop all periods post-treatment and regress the outcome, $Y$, on group dummies, time dummies, and group-time dummies. If the coefficient on group-time dummies is not significant this can serve as a decent test of pre-trends. The idea here is almost identical to the DID in that we are controlling for within-group and within-time variation and so what we get is variation within both group and time **before** treatment. So if there already was some strong pre-treatment trend we should pick it up.

Though to be frank, I am not sure people bother to do a formal test like this in practice. Every DID paper I have seen usually just relies on the visual test. The reason for this is simply that in almost any practical case a significant pre-treatment trend should appear in a visual evaluation. I think if the visual inspection is *concerning* then using the formal examination may prove useful. [Garthwaite et al. 2014](https://academic.oup.com/qje/article-abstract/129/2/653/1867903?redirectedFrom=PDF) (Section IV.D) is a good example of using the visual test to check for pre-trends.

Comment: Thank you for your dedicated answer. I am wondering one part "What you could do here is to drop all periods post-treatment and regress the outcome, Y, on group dummies, time dummies, and group-time dummies". What is the group dummies., time dummies, and group-time dummies here then? Are they the **whole sample of control and treatment** concatenating together during the pre-treatment periods?

Comment: These dummies are just indicators of control and treatment (groups), time periods prior to treatment, and their interaction. Yes you would *concatenate* the pre-treatment periods for this exercise.

Comment: excuse me, I am surprising about "their interaction" here, what does this mean during the pre-treatment period then? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry if this is unclear, I mean you should use [two-way fixed effects](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/286738/321865) and you should be checking for significance for the two-way dummies.